# AWS Target Groups, Target automatically deletes after a while

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

The target in my target group automatically deletes after a while (1 month). Please has anyone experience this ?

Comment: Is the target an EC2 instance? Are you using Auto Scaling? Are you sure the instance was not simply terminated by you explicitly or through some Auto Scaling action?

Comment: Yes i am using auto scaling. Its an Elastic Beanstalk instance. I just noticed that it happens whenever there is a managed update.

Comment: You can check the docs for what happens during [Beanstalk managed updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-platform-update-managed.html) and what level of control you have over the process.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your update configuration is set to immutable or if there is a scheduling scale action configurated in Beanstalk.

Comment: its not set to immutable.